# Access on attribute of extended class from SuperClass

Tags: c#, .net, class, attributes

I have the following classes and I need to know if DocPage class have the attribute SessionRequired into the method Render():

```
public class DocPageBase
{
   void Render()
   {
      // Have extended class SessionRequired?
   }
}

[SessionRequired]
public class DocPage : DocPageBase
{
   // Some properties and methods
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Regards,

Gerard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `GetType()` to get the actual type, and then [`Type.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx) to check for the presence of the attribute.

```
void Render()
{
    if (GetType().IsDefined(typeof(SessionRequiredAttribute), false)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: And If I need to get some attribute properties? For example:

[Cacheable(Cacheable.CaheScope.Session)]

...how can I get "Cacheable.CaheScope.Session"?

Comment: Then use `Type.GetCustomAttributes`.