# Check if derived class have an annotation from super class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, annotations

I need to check, form super class, if derived class have a specific annotation:

```
public class SuperClass
{
  public boolean hasAnnotation()
  {
    //super_class_method_code
  }
}

@annotationToCheck
public class DerivedClass extends SuperClass
{
   //derived_class_code
}
```

It is possible in Java? I know how to do in C# but in Java I can't find any solution... :(

Thank you!!!

Comment: This is the solution in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605884/access-on-attribute-of-extended-class-from-superclass/10605907#10605907

Comment: [may this help][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504870/how-to-test-if-one-java-class-extends- another-at-runtime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your instance is actually of the subclass type, this is as easy as defining the method in the supertype to have the following implementation:

```
this.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(annotationToCheck.class);
```

As the `this` is an instance of DerivedClass, the getClass returns DerivedClass and the check works.

Note2: As @Pshemo mentions in the comments, this only works when the annotation is annotated with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.

Comment: +1 I will just add that this works for annotations with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` policy.

Comment: Ohhhhh!!!! I forgot specify @Retention( value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME ) and @Target( value = ElementType.TYPE) in my annotation!!! THANK YOU Hiery and Pshemo!!!

Comment: @Pshemo Good observation! Thanks for adding that.

Comment: Feel free to update you answer with this info or upvote my comment to make it more visible (for people who - like me at the begining - ware wondering why it is not working for them :)

Comment: @HieryNomus I removed () from class declarations in OP question so Note 1 is pointless now (sorry ;p)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting derived classes using [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) project. This reflections project has dependencies( slf4j,log4j and javassist etc).

**Note:** Derived classes should be in mentioned package only.

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.Reflections;

public class Base {

    public Base() {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.sree.despacerivedclasskage");
        Set<Class<? extends Base>> classes = reflections
                .getSubTypesOf(Base.class);
        System.out.println(classes);
        for(Class clazz: classes){
            System.out.println(clazz.isAnnotationPresent(ToCheck.class));
        }

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base b = new Base();
}

}
```